# htaccess only allow internal use

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

I want a .htaccess that blocks the direct url to the .mp3 file.
But that can be used by the webpage with javascript.

So this need to be blocked:

```
http://www.domain.com/music/song.mp3
```

But this is allowed:

```
<a href="song" title="title song" class="play">play song</a>

$('.play').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var music = this.href.slice(22);
    $("#jplayer_N")
        .jPlayer("setMedia", {title: this.title, mp3: '/music/' +music+'.mp3'})
        .jPlayer("play");
});
```

I have this .htaccess now and this is only blocking everthing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp3)$ - [F]
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.doainm.com
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: There's no practical way that you can do that, unfortunately. Anyone who has access to the JS code can figure out how to pull the file from the server.

Comment: @Juhana WHat do you think is the best way to make it hard for users to get the file?

Comment: It is not practical buddy! You can't do that with .htaccess as it will keep blocking all .mp3 links whether its on JavaScript or in user address bar.

Comment: @GauravjotGaraya Hmm wierd. When i use my current htaccess it works in my browser. but not on mobile

Comment: .htaccess is server property and is truly independent of browser you are using. It must work same on mobile device too.